# In Gridx, How to replace the 'select all' header with a button?

Tags: javascript, dojo, gridx

In the Dojo GridX widget, I want to replace the 'select all' header with a button.  (The indirect select-all, to be specific).  This is the header above the row-select checkbox column, where when you select it, all the rows are selected.

I tried this, but it doesn't do anything:

```
grid.header.getHeaderNode("__indirectSelect__").innerHTML = "<div id='test'>TEST123</div>";
grid.header.refresh();
```

This does appear to set the innerHTML, but it is not reflected in the grid.  (I tried it on a normal column header just to test, and that also does not work).

Answer (score 1):

This is doable by overriding the IndirectSelectColumn class _createSelectAllBox() method.  Fairly simple once I found that class.